# Have AJAX execute whenever "create" controller is called

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I currently have a website and a swift app. Lets say the swift app creates some data and then sends the data to the "create" controller (using Ruby on Rails) so the recently pushed data shown on swift is updated on the website database. My question is that I want the newly added data to be shown on the website without having it be refreshed. I know AJAX and jQuery is the way to go. But how do I set an AJAX request react to whenever new data is pushed to the database?

Comment: Reverse the logic; use websockets or server side events to push data out from the server to the clients whenever new data is added